# Atualizar/Editar JSON no localStorage() com Java Script

Tags: javascript, json, aplicação-web, app, localstorage

Estou desenvolvendo um app de **anotações** em JavaScript, e gostaria de **editar** uma anotação salva em JSON no `localStorage`. Esse meu código está retornando apenas 1 (um) único objeto e sobrescreve os outros que estão armazenados, gostaria de saber como posso editar apenas o informado pelo usuário.

**Meu código:**

```
function saveEditedNote(title, text) {
    let notesEdit = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"))
    let note = {
        noteTitle : title,
        noteText : text
    }
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(note))            
}
```

**Meu localStorage:**

[image: localStorage()]

Comment: sim vai sobreescrever mesmo recuperando os valores anteriores na variável `notesEdit` não faz nada com ela e seta um novo objeto em "notes"

Comment: se eu setar um novo objeto, o antigo ainda continuara presente no storage, gostaria de editar o objeto ou então, remove-lo e adicionar o objeto "editado" no localSotrage

Comment: foi o que eu comentei, adicione o novo "note" ao "notesEdit" e faça set do "notesEdit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez isso possa te ajudar:

Você pode passa também o **id** e o **tipo** como parâmetro da sua **anotação** presente no seu storage para a função **saveEditedNote**, e assim fazer um filter dele passando os valores da sua anotação "editada" para o Array vindo do storage, logo após, **set** seu item no **localStorage**.

```
function saveEditedNote(id, type, title, text) {
    let notesEdit = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"))
        .filter(item => item.noteId !== id)

    notesEdit.push({
        noteTitle: title,
        noteText: text,
        noteType: type,
        noteId: id
    })
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(noteEdit))            
}
```

Comment: Obrigado!, era isso que eu precisava!